# Java, how to remove an Integer item in an ArrayList

Tags: java

Suppose I have such an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

After the adding operation:

```
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(5);
list.add(7);
```

I want to remove `number 2`, if I do

```
list.remove(2);
```

then `number 5` will be deleted, how could I delete `number 2`? And suppose I don't know the index of `number 2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly removing an Integer from a List<Integer>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534146/properly-removing-an-integer-from-a-listinteger)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

try this

```
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(2));
```

it will remove all elements with value = 2

you can also use this

```
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(2));
```

but it will remove only first occurence of 2

`list.remove(2)` does not work because it matches `List.remove(int i)` which removes element with the specified index

Answer (score 34):

There are two versions of `remove()` method:

- [`ArrayList#remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) that takes an `Object` to remove, and
- [`ArrayList#remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) that takes an `index` to remove.

With an `ArrayList<Integer>`, removing an integer value like `2`, is taken as index, as `remove(int)` is an exact match for this. It won't box `2` to `Integer`, and widen it.

A workaround is to get an `Integer` object explicitly, in which case widening would be prefered over unboxing:

```
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(2));
```

Answer (score 20):

instead of:

```
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(2));
```

you can of course just use:

```
list.remove((Integer) 2);
```

This will cast to an Integer object rather than primitive and then `remove()` by Object instead of Arraylist Index

Comment: So it will look for the object as long as it is an Integer and not an int right? For example- public void findById(Integer id){ Object item = array.get(id); } will return the value and not the position correct?

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you want : [ArrayList <Integer> with the get/remove method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117132/arraylist-integer-with-the-get-remove-method?rq=1)

```
list.remove(new Integer(2));
```

Comment: You should prefer `Integer.valueOf` over the constructor because it uses an internal cache to prevent unnecessary object creation.

Comment: This constructor is deprecated in Java 17.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is:

```
list.remove((Integer)5);
```

No unnecessary object creation, just casting the Index to Integer. BONUS: The simplest syntax.

Comment: Hi :), this answer has already been answered. If you have something to add to it, please include it as well, else consider removing this.

Comment: This is already answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54730522/12215054)

Comment: This still creates an object.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
list.remove(list.indexOf(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no explicit method for finding a particular list element and then removing it. You have to first find it with using the `indexOf` method:

```
int index = list.indexOf(element); // for your example element would be 2
list.remove(index);
```

Be aware that `indexOf` returns the index of the *first occurrence* of the object you give it, so you'll have to adjust accordingly for cases where you want to delete an item that is in the list multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
list.remove(0);
```

1. *remove(int index)*

   Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional
   operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts
   one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from
   the list.
2. *remove(Object o)*

   Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this
   list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it
   is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest
   index i such that (`o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))`) (if
   such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the
   specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result
   of the call).

Answer (score 1):

Simply if you use method like this it will remove element at index 2

YOUR ARRAYLIST: 2,3,5,7

> list.remove(2);

OUTPUT: 2,5,7

And if you use method like this it will remove element with value 2

YOUR ARRAYLIST: 2,3,5,7

> list.remove(Integer.valueOf(2));

OUTPUT: 3,5,7

Hope it help...

Answer (score 1):

In your case, this should also work,

```
list.removeIf(element -> element == 2);
```

Comment: Knew this question has been answered already, this is just an another way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You calling `list.remove(int)` method, but you need to call `list.remove(Object)` method.

There are several ways to do this:

1. `list.remove(Integer.valueOf(2)); // removes the first occurrence of 2`
2. `list.remove(list.indexOf(2)); // also removes the first occurrence of 2`
3. `list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(2)); // removes all occurrences of 2`

Answer (score -1):

you can use `list.remove(new Integer(i))` where i is the element you want to remove.

Answer (score -3):

```
list.remove(0);
```

0 represent element at index 0

and you have written `list.remove(2);` which means remove element at index 2 (i.e element at third place i.e 5   since `ArrayList` Start with index 0,1,2....)