# Is ist.remove(Integer.valueOf(2)); and list.remove((Integer) 2); are same? What is the difference between these codes?

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

You can read this and - [How to remove integer value from array list using remove() method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54730522)

Are they same? What is the best practice among them. If I want to write less code, can I use

```
list.remove((Integer) 2);
```

Comment: They do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

List.remove(int index) removes item at index.

List.remove(Integer item) removes first matching item in the list.