# The real differences between pop(), remove() and poll() in LinkedList<E>

Tags: java, arrays, list, difference

I've tried to find some information about differences between pop(), poll() and remove() in LinkedList but unfortunately I didn't find out any precision answer. The only information I have got was that:

-pop() removes first element of the list and throws exception if the list is empty
-remove() works the same as pop()
-poll() removes first element of the list but if the list is empty return null

And here's my question. Is it true that remove() and pop() have one small difference that I can add an Index to remove method? For example list.remove(3). I see that it is impossible to do with pop()

````
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

list.push(1);
list.push(2);
list.push(3);
list.push(4);
list.push(5);
```
list.pop(); //Output: 4, 3, 2, 1
//or
list.poll(); //Output: 4, 3, 2, 1
//or
list.remove(3); //Output: 5, 4, 3, 1
````

Comment: Read the java doc

Comment: The [javadoc on `Deque` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) to be exact.

Comment: `List<Integer>::remove(int x)` *is* somewhat tricky, though! ;(https://stackoverflow.com/q/4534146/592355, https://stackoverflow.com/q/21795376/592355)

Comment: `list.remove(int n)` will remove the `n`th element. `list.remove(Integer x)` will remove the first occurrence of element with value `x` from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, `LinkedList` has three `remove` methods. They have the same name, but differ in their parameter lists. Having several methods by the same name, but different parameter lists, is called "overloading".

So, to answer your question: There is no difference between `pop()` and `remove()`, but there is a difference between `pop()` and `remove(int index)`.

This is possible, because `remove()` and `remove(int index)` are two different methods. (Technically, `remove()` and `remove(int index)` could do totally different things. But that would be very bad practice, because any sensible person expects two methods that share the same name to do similar things.)

The [Java API documentation for LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) lists all available methods and explains their behavior.