# ArrayList .get and .add with variables Java

Tags: java, random, arraylist, get, addition

I am trying to make a program that generates 100 integers from 0 to 25 and store them in 3 arrays: one for all the numbers, one for even, one for odd. I am having trouble with adding the variable `n` to my arrays. My `.get` is also not working well. Thanks!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class randomdemo { 
    public static ArrayList randommethod()
    {
        int i = 0;

        ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList evenArray = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList oddArray = new ArrayList();

        while(i<=99)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.nextInt(25) + 0;

            myArray.add(n);

            if(myArray.get(i) % 1 == 0)
            {
                evenArray.add(n);
            }
            else
            {
                oddArray.add(n);
            }
            i++;
        }
        return myArray;
        return evenArray;
        return oddArray;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        randommethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you think `return` works?

Comment: Think about what `if(myArray.get(i) % 1 == 0)` does mathematically. There are also other problems but start here.

Comment: Kon, thanks and I'll change it to 2. But that was not really my question...

Comment: As @SotiriosDelimanolis mentioned, you need to read up on how `return` statements work (hint: you can't return more than once object from a method)

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117132/arraylist-integer-with-the-get-remove-method

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: @YoungDeezie Do you want 100 odds, 100 evens, 100 all, Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have three returns from a single method, and you don't use the result anyway. Please don't use [`raw-types`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). And, you could make those `List`(s) static so you can use them after calling your method. You should declare your `Random` before starting your loop. Finally, even is `% 2 == 0`. Something like,

```
static List<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
static List<Integer> evenArray = new ArrayList<>();
static List<Integer> oddArray = new ArrayList<>();

public static void randommethod() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int n = rand.nextInt(26); // <-- n + 0 is n. 0 to 25.
        myArray.add(n);
        if (n % 2 == 0) { // <-- test n, no need to get it again.
            evenArray.add(n);
        } else {
            oddArray.add(n);
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    randommethod();
    System.out.println("All: " + myArray);
    System.out.println("Even: " + evenArray);
    System.out.println("Odd: " + oddArray);
}
```

Comment: Doing this way, at most you get 50 odds and 50 evens

Comment: @user3437460 That is not true.

Comment: You can simplify the code to `(n%2==0? even: odd).add(n);` but that’s a matter of coding style…

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Hmm I am not sure what exactly OP wants, does he wants 100 evens, 100 odds, 100 all numbers?

Comment: @user3437460: you should understand randomness; of course, it is perfectly possible to get `100` odd and `0` even numbers or vice versa. What the OP wants is clearly visible when you look at the code example contained it the question.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get an error on the myArray.add(n);

Comment: @YoungDeezie Then you didn't change it to `static List<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<>();`. Don't use raw-types.

Comment: Elliot, I did that and then ctrl shift o to import the stuff, but now the .add is fixed, but the ' static List<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<>();' is an error

Comment: @YoungDeezie What error? And those are both in `java.util.` Make sure you didn't pick `java.awt.List`

Comment: I used these 3 imports: import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

Comment: What error are you getting? If you're using Java 6 or 5 then you can't use the diamond operator `<>` (but those versions aren't supported anymore anyway).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66771/discussion-between-young-deezie-and-elliott-frisch).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
ArrayList<Integer> all = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//Add 100 integers of all numbers
for(int x=0; x<100; x++)
    all.add(rnd.nextInt(26)) //26 gives random 0-25

//Add 100 integers of even numbers
int x=0;
while(x<100){
    int rand = rnd.nextInt();
    if(rand % 2 == 0){
       even.add(rand);
       x++
    }     
}
```

Generating odd numbers are same as the way you generate even numbers. Just change the condition to `if (rand % 2 != 0)`